# Microsoft VSTO extension

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I am looking for an extension of the Microsoft VSTO framework. I am still in the learning stages so I could be wrong, but I am finding that the capabilities that it has are very minimal. Is there an extension of this framework that is easier to work with? I'm currently looking into [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/), but it seems like it's more for external applications using office than for add-ins.

An example of how I think it is very minimal. I wish to get the email address (`stack@overflow.com`) for the recipients when the user clicks send in Outlook. But the only thing available is the exchange address (`/O=ORGANIZATION_NAME /OU=EXCHANGE_GROUP /CN=RECIPIENTS /CN=USER_NAME`). This function is available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184624.aspx), but this seems like it should just be available in the VSTO framework.

Thanks,
McAngus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSTO does not expose anything the Outlook Object Model does not expose. Use `AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmntpAddress`.